# Are there free Mac or Windows distributions for only dev/testing purposes?

Tags: testing, operating-system, cross-platform

I wish to test/debug/dev my software on all three popular platforms. I am wondering that am I allowed to gain an access to a free copy (e.g. a virtual OS) to test my software on Windows and Mac?

I wonder what most developers do to test their software. You obviously need the actual Win/Mac to be sure your software works as is, but you don't want to be paying for all OSes especially because you don't use them, other than test your software on them.

I am working on something that requires extensive testing. It's made for developers, so, even if I happen to have extra cash to waste on OSes I don't use or like, I can't demand that for every developer using my product.

What are my options here?

Comment: It would be nice if there was a cloud testing environment with several different operating systems available to deploy on. Kind of like an Amazon EC2 but with the ability to actually deploy to more than one 'template machine', for a set amount of time. I've been tossing this idea around for awhile but can't really see a way to make it affordable. Another idea would be an Open Computing like distributed platform, but in that case I'm not sure how to make it secure. Anyone want to collab? Haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macintosh operating systems will only run on Macintosh hardware.  There are "hackintosh" hacks out there were people have hacked the OS to run on non-Macintosh hardware, but by the very nature of them they are not trustworthy to test your software on, because it might run on a hackintosh but not on a legitimate version because it relies on the very hack that made the OS run on non-Macintosh hardware.

Besides, there is a word for trying to get free copies of something the manufacturer wants you to pay for: theft.

That said, I saw a demo from a guy from Sun.  He'd installed OpenSolaris as his main OS on a MacBookPro, and then had Windows and Mac and Solaris virtual machines running using VirtualBox.  And because the virtual machines were run on ZFS, it was very easy for him to restore them to the pre-test condition.  It made for a consistent testing environment every time.

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking for illegal sources.

Comment: Yes piracy exists, but that's not what I am looking for. If I were to make my own platform, I would make sure there is a free way to develop for it, which does not mean you can enjoy the entire OS with all its functionalities, but just test/run software on it.

Comment: +1 to @Paul for mentioning Virtual Box - free virtualization software that 'just works'.

Comment: @rFactor, I notice that you're not as rich as Bill Gates or Steve Jobs.  Apple and Microsoft have their model for making their OSes popular and getting apps developed for them, and it's not yours.

Comment: Why are we making this personal? It's a straight-forward question.

Comment: @brian, because the OP is asking for a way to do something which is illegal.

Comment: @paul I was hoping to find ways to do that something legally. If I were to do something illegally, I would not be here.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, you get yourself an MSDN licence. It's not free but you get the entire swag of operating systems to test your software with.

I'm not sure what your concern is for *other* developers. This is *your* software and tour responsibility to test on various operating systems. Other developers will generally only be testing on the single OS they use or, if they use your code to create their own applications for multiple operating systems, they will already have that cost.

Comment: Think of it more like a framework/library. My customers are developers who develop alongside with the toolkit I provide.

Comment: Then the products _they_ develop with your framework are _their_ responsibility. They will need to get their own OS' anyway.

Comment: Last time I looked, an MSDN license cost over $1500 a year.

Comment: Hence my "it's not free" comment. The OS variant is about $1200 (the ultimate will set you back a cool $20K so is probably not suitable for the vast majority) but, in all honesty, if you can't afford $1200, you're not running a successful business and you should probably think about a change :-) Buying all the OS' included in that separately would be more than that and it gives you a _lot_ more as well.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft supplies VPC images specifically for testing websites in IE 6,7,8 and 9 on XP, Vista and Windows 7: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11575

Comment: This was some nice information - I'm looking for these kinds of things! Let me have a look.

Comment: You'll noticed that all of these images require you to own a legitimate version of Windows to run VirtualPC on.